# MongoDB Java driver: Undefined values are not shown

Tags: java, json, mongodb, bson

Open mongo shell and create a document with a undefined value:

```
> mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.0
connecting to: test
> use mydb
switched to db mydb
> db.mycol.insert( {a_number:1, a_string:"hi world", a_null:null, an_undefined:undefined} );
> db.mycol.findOne();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51c2f28a7aa5079cf24e3999"),
        "a_number" : 1,
        "a_string" : "hi world",
        "a_null" : null,
        "an_undefined" : null
}
```

As we can see, javascript translates the "undefined" value (stored in the db) to a "null" value, when showing it to the user. But, in the db, the value is still "undefined", as we are going to see with java.

Let's create a "bug_undefined_java_mongo.java" file, with the following content:

```
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;


public class bug_undefined_java_mongo
{

    String serv_n = "myserver";     // server name
    String db_n   = "mydb";         // database name
    String col_n  = "mycol";        // collection name


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {        
        new bug_undefined_java_mongo().start();        
    }


    public void start()
    {

        pr("Connecting to server ...");      
        MongoClient cli = null;
        try
        {
            cli = new MongoClient( serv_n );           
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            pr("Can't connecto to server: " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        if (cli == null)
        {
            pr("Can't connect to server");
            System.exit(1);
        }


        pr("Selecting db ...");
        DB db_res = cli.getDB( db_n );


        pr("Selecting collection ...");      
        DBCollection col = db_res.getCollection( col_n );


        pr("Searching documents ...");
        DBCursor cursor = null;
        try
        {
            cursor = col.find( );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            pr("Can't search for documents: " + e);
            System.exit(1);
        }


        pr("Printing documents ...");
        try
        {
            while (cursor.hasNext())
            {
                Object doc_obj = cursor.next();                
                System.out.println("doc: " + doc_obj);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            pr("Can't browse documents: " + e);
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            pr("Closing cursor ...");
            cursor.close();
        }

    }


    public void pr(String cad)
    {
        System.out.println(cad);
    }    

}
```

After compiling and running it, we get this:

```
Connecting to server ...
Selecting db ...
Selecting collection ...
Searching documents ...
Printing documents ...
doc: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "51c2f0f85353d3425fcb5a14"} , "a_number" : 1.0 , "a_string" : "hi world" , "a_null" :  null }
Closing cursor ...
```

We see that the "a_null:null" pair is shown, but... the "an_undefined:undefined" pair has disappeared! (both the key and the value).

Why? Is it a bug?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `undefined` is not supported by the java driver as there is no equivalent mapping in  java.

Other drivers such as pymongo and the js shell handles this differently by casting `undefined` to `None` when representing the data, however it is a separate datatype and is deprecated in the [bson spec](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification).

If you need it in the java driver then you will have to code your own decoder factory and then set it like so:

```
collection.setDBDecoderFactory(MyDecoder.FACTORY);
```

A minimal example that has defined handling for `undefined` and factory is available on github in the [horn of mongo](https://github.com/nlloyd/horn-of-mongo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/nlloyd/hornofmongo/bson/HornOfMongoBSONDecoder.java) repo.

Answer (score 0):

I see, creating a factory could be a solution.

Anyway, probably many developers would find it useful the posibility of enabling a mapping in the driver to convert automatically "undefined" values to "null" value. For example, by calling a mapUndefToNull() method:

```
cli = new MongoClient( myserver );
cli.mapUndefToNull(true);
```

In my case, I'm running a MapReduce (it is Javascript code) on my collections, and I am having to explicitly convert the undefined values (generated when accessing to non existent keys) to null, in order to avoid Java driver to remove it:

```
try { value = this[ key ] }  catch(e) {value = null}
if (typeof value == "undefined")  value = null;      // avoid Java driver to remove it
```

So, as a suggestion, I'd like the mapUndefToNull() method to be added to the Java driver. If possible.

Thank you